# Beginning Webservice with Joomla

Tags: joomla2.5

I am new to joomla 2.5. I need to design application which is to be used by STB(SET TOP BOX) or TV Application. Is it possible to use below features with Joomla 2.5 ?

1. Authenticate users where credentials are passed from STB or TV via POST method.
2. Calling Webservices after authentication, custom string format needs to be return instead of JSON or XML.
3. Is it possible to host file with encryption from developed administrator component ?

Any Ideas? Any good beginners book for Joomla 2.5 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. yes if you previously download the login page and grab the token, which is a dynamic security feature
2. no problem there, just make sure you end your controller method with

   exit

so the template won't be output.

1. I can't figure out what you mean. Encrypted files will not be accepted on the Joomla Extension Directory, but you can use them in custom components.

Beginners books: really depends on your php and overall development experience.  The reference and plenty of guides are on docs.joomla.org (section developers), but check here first for any questions, there are plenty of answers on Joomla!